# Angular interpolation for variable with percent sign in its name

Tags: angular, angular-template

I need to display value of variable with percent sign in name: `Wifi_%`.

When I use`{{Wifi_%}}` in template, I got `Failed to compile widget html. Error: Cannot redefine property: ɵfac` while compiling my widget.

When I use`{{Wifi}}` in template, value is being displayed. But I can't modify the name because I got it from third-party data source.

Is there any interpolation option in Angular to cover my case?

Comment: Why can't you map/transform from the third-party data structure to something more useful? That would also isolate your code from the details of that data source.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can, but I wish to avoid transformation overhead because data could be updated every seconds and there are up to 10 data sources with the same naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign it to an object :

```js
state = { 'Wifi_%': 12 };
```

You can then use array syntax to read it

```
{{ state['Wifi_%'] }}
```

Comment: Should be noted that jonrsharpe gave you the correct approach (map to a better model), I'm just answering the question in case someone stumbles upon this in the future

Comment: For most cases such approach would lead to some overhead as well as transformation, but fortunately for me I already have such object, so will mark this approach as answer.

Comment: Another possibility would be to create a getter or static property in the controller and assign the Wifi_% variable to it and use the property controller in template.

Comment: @DaSch that would mean a getter for each property, while true, not convenient IMO

Comment: @temp_user it's hard to tell how this should look like without knowing the exact shape and access of the datasource. Another possibility could be to use lodash mapKey to create an object that has the _% removed. And if it's already an object why is his example about trying to access the directly from the controller and not from an object?

Comment: Just for clarification. It is [custom widget](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/#latest-values-widget) for Thingsboard platform. Each widget has `ctx` and `ctx.$scope` object. The last one is Angular component context. To access data in template, I should assign it to `$scope` as following `$scope.MY_VAR = 123;` or  `$scope['MY_VAR'] = 123;`. When the data has been updated, widget receives array of datasources and I assign value from each of them to `$scope[datasource[i].label] = datasource[i].value;` Then....

Comment: ....Then if the label is without `%`, the template placeholder is the following `{{SOME_VAR_NAME}}` , but in case of  `%` in the name of variable I can't do this. @temp_user "reminds" me that `$scope` has cyclic link to `ctx` (the parent object) thus I can do the following in template `{{ctx.$scope['MY_VAR_NAME_WITH_%']}}` ))))